# Automatically Substituting In A Series Into An Integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I'm working on an algorithm that includes some difficult integration, dealing with $\mathrm{erf}(t)$ functions, for example. One term in the algorithm is this:

```
Integrate[Exp[-2 t^2] t^2 Erf[t], {t, 0, x}]
```

which integrates just fine. Next, we have another term:

```
Integrate[Exp[-2 t^2] t^2 Erf[Sqrt[3] t], {t, 0, x}],
```

where we have added the $\sqrt{3}$ in the argument of the $\mathrm{erf}(t)$. *Mathematica* will integrate this if we approximate either $\exp(-2 t^2)$ or $\mathrm{erf}(\sqrt{3}t)$ as Maclaurin series, for example.

What I want *Mathematica* to do is if it can't do an integral that includes an $\mathrm{erf}(t)$ function, then it would sub in Maclaurin series for the function and try again. I don't want to sub in the series prematurely (for all instances of $\mathrm{erf}(t)$) because the series are not that great and I'm using them more as a crutch. Since these integrations are automated (they are part of a `Do` loop), I can't do this substitution manually.

If there is an option that already exists, or that could be created that would accomplish this, I would be over the moon.

Thank you!

Comment: Incidentally, does anybody know why the indefinite symbolic integration normally takes *much* less time than the definite? Even when the substitutions needed are straightforward.

Comment: What if approach by @george2079 below isn't successful, because the integrand is that complex for example; should the procedure call itself again, this time approximating `Exp[t^2]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can be done with a straightforward change of variable..

```
Integrate[Exp[-2/3 (t)^2] t^2 Erf[ t], {t, 0, x Sqrt[3]}]/(3 Sqrt[3])
```

[image]

numerical check..

```
% /. x -> 2 // N
```

> 0.137056

```
NIntegrate[Exp[-2 t^2] t^2 Erf[Sqrt[3] t], {t, 0, 2}]
```

> 0.137056

a bit puzzling that `Integrate` cant do that on its own.

generically

```
Integrate[Exp[b t^2] t^2 Erf[a t], {t, 0, x}]
```

transforms to:

```
Integrate[ Exp[b (tp/a)^2] (tp/a)^2 Erf[tp]/a, {tp, 0, a x}]
```

which evaluates successfully (just  a bit unwieldy to post though)

---

The auto substitution you wanted can be done something like this:

```
int[expt_] := Module[{res},
  res = Integrate[expt, {t, 0, x}];
  If[TrueQ[Head[res] == Integrate], 
   Integrate[expt /. Erf[ a_ t] :> Normal@Series[Erf[a t], {t, 0, 6}],
    {t, 0, x}], res]]
int[Exp[-2 t^2] t^2 Erf[t]]
int[Exp[-2 t^2] t^2 Erf[Sqrt[3] t]]
```

> [image]

Comment: Beautiful response! I've plotted the exact result with the series result and there was quite a bit of error (I wasn't sure how to find the exact function until you showed with change of variables)! I think I'll try to use your scheme to do the substitution of variables, otherwise I'll resort to using more terms in the series... Thank you so much!

Comment: the series solution is only good for `x<1`, about 20 terms gives a good result for `x=1` though.

Comment: It looks like for the change of variables to work we would substitute $t \rightarrow t/a$ where $a$ is the parameter in $Erf(a t)$, and then do another substitution for the upper $x$ bound. In your code you used a pattern to track what $a$ is, but that's when you were directly substituting it with the series. Can I track this $a$ without a direct substitution? Otherwise Mathematica doesn't know what it is...

Comment: i put the generic integral variable substitution in the answer.